# Rearrangement data using r

Tags: r

I would like to ask how can I rearrange my dataset that fulfils the following

[

```html
Original :

Group    Value_y    Value_z
  1         m          a
  1         n          a
  2         o          b
  2         p          b
  
Intended: 

Group   Value_a    Value_b
  1       m          n
  2       o          p
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7kJx.png)

which involves separating value_y according to value_z and adding a new column according to the group number. Will potential need to average a separate column's values and add as a new column the same way.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably : `dcast(setDT(df), Group~rowid(Value_z), value.var = 'Value_y')` using `data.table`

Comment: and if you need to create a new mean variable, do something like YourDataTable[, newvariable := mean(yourvariable), by = yourgroupvariable]. I guess this could be somehow done in one step as well (create a new data.table from your data.frame by category while at the same time creating a mean variable by that same category) but it would be harder to read for people reading your code. Why don't you make this an answer, @RonakShah ? p.s. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table` we can use `dcast` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Group~rowid(Value_z), value.var = 'Value_y')

#   Group 1 2
#1:     1 m n
#2:     2 o p
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Value_y = c("m", "n", 
"o", "p"), Value_z = c("a", "a", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dplyr solution. Define

```
Uneven = seq(1, dim(A)[1] - 1, by = 2)
Even = seq(2, dim(A)[1], by = 2)
```

with

```
A = data.frame(Group = c(1, 1, 2, 2), Value_y = c("m", "n", "o", "p"))
```

Then, you can use the pipe and some dplyr functionality to get

```
A2 = A %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Row_1 = Value_y[Uneven]) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Row_2 = Value_y[Even]) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Value_y) %>% 
  dplryr::slice(1)
```

and the output

```
> A2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Group Row_1 Row_2
  <dbl> <fct> <fct>
1     1 m     n    
2     2 o     p
```

Note that this solution presupposes two-pairs of Groups, i.e. an even number of observations.